# Filtering attribut table QGIS

Tags: attribute-table, filter

I try to filter for catchwords by using the attribute table. I need to filter all attributes which starts with "industrial". The problem ist that the attributes are sometimes named as "industrialpark" or "industrialzone" or "industrialarea".

Is there a way to filter for just a special part of a catchword?

I could imagine that there must be a way using the "select by expression" tool and say something like "fieldname = 'indust...'" or "fieldname = 'industrial...'" , so that qgis prints out all catchwords which starts with the searched part of the word.

Comment: Dear [Ma Fo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/85647/ma-fo), I can refer you [to this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp), where you can find more about **LIKE Operator** which was demonstrated in answer by [ThingumaBob](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93656/thingumabob). If you are interested to find "industial" in any position then you can use a filter with `"fieldname" LIKE '%industrial%'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a general expression to be used wherever you want, try

```
"fieldname" LIKE 'industrial%'
```

where the `%` wildcard matches any or no character following the string.